# Calcular a soma e média de uma sequência numérica

Tags: python

Na sequência 3,5,7,9,11,13,15. Descubra o padrão da sequência e:

- a) Faz um programa para mostrar 12 valores de essa sequência iniciado por 3.
- b) Mostre a soma de 'TODOS' valores (12 valores).
- c) Mostre o valor médio de 'TODOS' valores (12 valores).

Comecei assim, dai me enrolei. Me ajudem.

```
x = 3
while x < 27:
   print(x)
   x = x + 2
```

Comment: Já conseguiu a letra (a), mas teve dificuldades nas outras? Se você precisa da soma de todos os valores, não bastaria você ir somando cada valor de `x`? E a média requerida em (c) é a divisão entre a soma e a quantidade de elementos.

Comment: Sim, não sei como fazer essa soma, é que sou novo em programação e to meio perdido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Nota:** é importante salientar que existem infinitas séries numéricas que satisfazem a sequência `{3,5,7,9,11,13,15,...}` (ver final da resposta), então solicitar para o usuário identificar **o** padrão não faz sentido algum e, principalmente, se qualquer uma das séries fosse implementada, seria uma solução válida. A solução `a_n = 2*n + 1` só é, possivelmente, a mais trivial delas e, provavelmente por isso, será a esperada pelo professor.

Você já fez a letra (a), mas há como melhorar. Da forma que fez, você precisa inicialmente saber que para exibir os 12 elementos solicitados a condição será `x < 27`, mas e se for solicitado 20, 50 ou até nem saber quantos serão? Nesses casos sua solução não funcionaria. O mais simples é você criar um contador que controle quantos números serão exibidos:

```
quantidade = 12
exibidos = 0
numero = 3

while exibidos < quantidade:
    print(numero)
    numero += 2
    exibidos += 1
```

Assim, serão mostrados os 12 números da sequência. Se alterar `quantidade` para 50, mostrarão os 50. Já, para a letra (b), você precisa acumular a soma em outra variável:

```
quantidade = 12
exibidos = 0
numero = 3
soma = 0

while exibidos < quantidade:
    print(numero)
    soma += numero
    numero += 2
    exibidos += 1

print('Soma = ', soma)
```

E, finalmente, a média será a divisão entre a soma e a quantidade de números:

```
media = soma / quantidade
```

Ficando:

```
quantidade = 12
exibidos = 0
numero = 3
soma = 0

while exibidos < quantidade:
    print(numero)
    soma += numero
    numero += 2
    exibidos += 1

print('Soma = ', soma)

media = soma / quantidade

print('Média = ', media)
```

---

**Colaboração do [Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado)**

Como estamos lidando com sequências numéricas, a continuidade da função geradora não é um requisito, assim, por exemplo, a sequência gerada por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Satisfaz a sequência dada no enunciado, mas o termo seguinte seria 21 (e não 17). A sequência seria: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 21, 23, 25, ...

**Colaboração do [Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco)**

Outra bem mais simples de entender é a sequência dada por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto é, calcular o resto da divisão de 2x+1 por 17, assim a sequência gerada seria: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 0, 2, 4, 6, ..., que também satisfaz a sequência dada no enunciado, mas o termo seguinte não é o 17.

Comment: Mano obrigadão, era isso mesmo, vou dar uma estudada no código...

Answer (score 0):

Sequência que deverá ser mostrada: **3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25**.

No lugar de `while x < 27` coloque `x <= 25` e criar também uma variável auxiliar para ir guardando a soma dos valores.

*Exemplo:*  `y = 0` (inicie-o com 0 para não sobrar sujeira das somas e dar valores errados).

Não sei como se faz em Phyton, fiz um exemplo usando a lógica de Java.

```
x = 3;
y = 0;

   while x < 27:
       print(x)
         y = x + 2;
         x++;
```

Comment: E qual a diferença entre a condição `x <= 25` e `x < 27`, sendo que `x` será ímpar?

Comment: Ô, desculpa pelo erro! Não havia reparado nisso. Acredito que utilizando `x <= 25` pode ser de melhor entendimento (pelo menos pra mim, é. Fazem dois anos que iniciei com programação, e, quanto mais claro e óbvio cada lógica/variável que eu uso, o entendimento ao meu ponto de vista é melhor.). Você testou utilizando uma variável auxiliar?

Comment: Fui eu que errei, era x <= 25 mesmo ele tem que mostrar esses valores 3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25 Soma de todos esses números é 168

Comment: Tente fazer uma variável auxiliar para realizar a soma dos valores e depois é só dividir por 12 (que é o tanto de elementos) para fazer sua média.

Comment: Maria Clara você poderia mostrar como é?

Comment: Eu não sei programar em Phyton. Mas vou usar a mesma lógica com JAVA, pode ser? Seria mais ou menos: `y = x + 2` aí, enquanto o `x <=25` ele vai somando (quando utilizado *x++*, ele vai acumulando até chegar o resultado que foi definido por você, que nesse caso, seria `x <= 25`). Depois que ele somar todos os valores, você printa o **Y**. Depois de printar, você faz aquele cálculo matemático: y / 2 (cálculo da média) e printa **Y** novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Segue a solução:

```
# Geracao da sequencia contendo 12 valores
seq = list(range(3, 27, 2))

# Extrai valores da sequencia iniciados com '3'
a = [ n for n in seq if str(n)[0] == '3' ]

# Calcula soma dos valores da sequencia
b = sum(seq)

# Calcula a media dos valores da sequencia 
c = sum(seq) / float(len(seq))

print(seq)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Saída:

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25]
[3]
168
14.0
```

Comment: Usando `range`, não seria mais simples `list(range(3, 27, 2))`? E poderia explicar o que seria o objeto `a`?

Comment: `a`, `b` e `c` são as respostas dos respectivos itens da pergunta. `a` trata-se dos `valores da sequência iniciado por 3`.

Comment: Ah, sim, mas acredito que `seq` já seria a resposta da `a` xD

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss:  Ou será que *mostrar 12 valores de essa sequência iniciado por 3* não seria algo como: `print([ int('3' + str(n)) for n in seq ])` ?!?!